# search in a range of latitude and longitude from text file on server in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to search in a text file (available on a url) , there is latitude, longitude and other information separated by commas. 
I need to search lat lon which is nearest to user's selected lat lon in app.
Code is done to read that file and search but it do not work perfectly. 
Please let me know , how should I approach in this type of situation.
1)File get updated in real time , so I need to call url and read file every time user select location and click to get information.
2)And then search for nearest lat lon to the user's selected lat lon.

NSDICTIONARY DATA GETTING :-

```
(
    {
    "altitude_m" = "90.0";
    engName = “Station 1”;
    grkName = "\U039d\U03ad\U03b1 \U039c\U03ac\U03ba\U03c1\U03b7 \U0391\U03c4\U03c4\U03b9\U03ba\U03ae\U03c2";
    "humidity_P" = "50.0";
    lat = "38.058873";
    "local_time" = "16:20";
    lon = "23.976741";
    "pressure_hPA" = "1019.9";
    "rain_mm" = "0.0";
    "tem_C" = "17.2";
    "wind_Gusts_khm" = "51.5";
    "wind_degrees" = "22.5";
    "wind_kmh" = "25.7";
}
{
    "altitude_m" = "90.0";
    engName = “Station 2”;
    grkName = "\U039d\U03ad\U03b1 \U039c\U03ac\U03ba\U03c1\U03b7 \U0391\U03c4\U03c4\U03b9\U03ba\U03ae\U03c2";
    "humidity_P" = "50.0";
    lat = "38.048873";
    "local_time" = "16:20";
    lon = "23.876741";
    "pressure_hPA" = "1019.9";
    "rain_mm" = "0.0";
    "tem_C" = "17.2";
    "wind_Gusts_khm" = "51.5";
    "wind_degrees" = "22.5";
    "wind_kmh" = "25.7";
}
{
    "altitude_m" = "90.0";
    engName = “Station 3”;
    grkName = "\U039d\U03ad\U03b1 \U039c\U03ac\U03ba\U03c1\U03b7 \U0391\U03c4\U03c4\U03b9\U03ba\U03ae\U03c2";
    "humidity_P" = "50.0";
    lat = "38.059873";
    "local_time" = "16:20";
    lon = "23.986741";
    "pressure_hPA" = "1019.9";
    "rain_mm" = "0.0";
    "tem_C" = "17.2";
    "wind_Gusts_khm" = "51.5";
    "wind_degrees" = "22.5";
    "wind_kmh" = "25.7";
}
```

// MATCHING FUNCTION :-

```
-(void)matchLAtLongNow: (NSString *)latitude :(NSString *)longitude {


CLLocationCoordinate2D pinlocation;

pinlocation.latitude   = [latitude doubleValue];

pinlocation.longitude  = [longitude doubleValue];


float minLat = pinlocation.latitude - (searchDistance / 69);

float maxLat = pinlocation.latitude + (searchDistance / 69);


float minLon = pinlocation.longitude - searchDistance / fabs(cos(deg2rad(pinlocation.latitude))*69);
float maxLon = pinlocation.longitude + searchDistance / fabs(cos(deg2rad(pinlocation.longitude))*69);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"lat <= %f AND lat >= %f AND lon <= %f AND lon >= %f",
                          maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon];

MatchedTxtArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:applePred];


}
```

//GETTING ERROR
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber _fastCStringContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175426460'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionaries return NSNumbers. Check where you call matchAtLongNow: You probably have NSNumbers where you're expecting strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked that there is Strings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a geo search, as opposed inclusion within some thresholds.  I'd reformulate to something like this:

```
NSArray *objects; // this is your parsed file, an array of dictionaries
CLLocation *userLocation;  // this is your user location

// sort the dictionary in order of distance to the userLocation
NSArray *sortedObjects = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *objA,NSDictionary *objB) {
    CLLocationDistance distanceA = [self distanceToObject:objA from:userLocation];
    CLLocationDistance distanceB = [self distanceToObject:objB from:userLocation];
    return (NSComparisonResult)(distanceB-distanceA);
}];
```

`sortedObjects` will contain the dictionaries sorted from nearest to farthest from the `userLocation`  We just need a function that produces the distance from the lat/lon values in the dictionary to the userLocation...

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceToObject:(NSDictionary *)object from:(CLLocation *)location {
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = [object[@"lat"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [object[@"lob"] doubleValue];
    CLLocation *objectLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    return [objectLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
}
```